# Proposal: answer-to-comment conversion for non-diamonds

Tags: feature-request, not-an-answer

Of late, there is a giant population of 'not an answer' flags on display, and most of these are comments planted in answers.

It seems to me that answer-to-comment conversion is non-destructive. So, I propose:

If an answer has <=0 votes, anyone with 10k should be able to comment-ize it. Anyone below 10k can flag 'not an answer'.

Comment: It's mostly harmless, but one thing to note is that unlike other moderation tools available to 10k users answer-to-comment conversion is not reversible by other community members.

Comment: Point taken, but I think the volume of mistakes requiring diamond repair will be a tiny fraction of the number of conversions.

Comment: Possibly. To determine if that's the case we'd need to look at how many "not an answer" flags so far were valid and needed conversion, I think.

Comment: Three outcomes to a flag: nuthin, delete, convert. My bigger concern is that the diamonds think that deletion is much more frequently appropriate. Can we get these stats?

Comment: It's a fine line; there could also be many of those flagged answers are not even suitable for converting to a comment, they are just better off deleted, which is a call that a diamond mod can make when they process the flag.